# Passing parameter to query for Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am using following code and trying to get data by given parameters.  I donot know how to pass the parameter value to my query.

```vb
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String

con.ConnectionString = "
                 PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                 Data Source = D:\.Net Programs\DB Experiments\AddressBook.mdb"

        con.Open()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts where Name=? and City=?"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "AddressBook")
        con.Close()
```

Answer (score 3):

I would first create an OleDbCommand object and use this object to create a OleDbDataAdapter

```
Imports Data.OleDb

dim cmd as new OleDbCommand
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts where Name=? and City=?"

' Here we add the parameters in the same order they appear in the
' CommandText. The Name of the paramters can be anything when using
' a Jet database, only the order is important.
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).value = "SLaks"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", OleDbType.VarChar).value = "New-York"

Dim da as new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

' Here you can use the Data Adapter as you would normally do.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please advise what imports are necessary.  At the moment it is giving error on OleDbType, OleDbDataAdapter

Comment: I think you only need to import Data.OleDb.

Answer (score -1):

Call

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("paramName", someValue);
```

Comment: What is parameter name while in query we have ?

Comment: I believe that the parameter name wouldn't matter.

Comment: I tried it like ("paramName", txtName.text) it returned error  One or more parameters not given

Comment: Try changing `?` to `@paramName`.

Comment: Google addwithvalue.  The first hit should be the MSDN page.  Looking at their example it seems you need to use a SQLCommand object if you're passing parameters.

Comment: @Banjoe: `OleDbCommand` also has an `AddWithValue` method.  I just don't know how it behaves with unnamed parameters.

Comment: @SLaks: You seem to be unfamiliar with Jet SQL syntax.  The @ symbol is not used.  @Furhan: If you want to call your parameters, for example, "NameParam" and "CityParam" then your query text should be this: `"SELECT * FROM tblContacts where Name=[NameParam] and City=[CityParam]"`

Answer (score -1):

Why not directly build the final Sql ?

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts where Name='" & myName & "' and City='" & myCity & "'"
```

Would there be a difference in performance or security or...?

Comment: Isn't that generally deprecated because of the danger of SQL injection attack? I realize it is not common for MS Access, but it is possible.

Comment: I would say that concerns over SQL injection in relation to Access are vastly overblown. Jet/ACE shouldn't be used as a data store on a web server in the first place, and in the environments where Access/Jet/ACE is appropriate, the user has to have full access through the file system to the data file, so worrying about SQL injection is like having a car with no doors and worrying about whether the car alarm is turned on or not.

Comment: @David: I think so too. It's a "good practice" that's engraved in  developer's mind, but since you can't block the injection from Jet, it's useless in that case.

Comment: However isn't it the trend these days to make it possible to change the database with as little pain as possible?

Comment: @Remou: I would think that whether or not you implement your interaction with parameters or not depends on what interface you are using to work with the data. Within Access itself, there's often very little benefit to doing that. From VB.NET, I'd think it would be standard practice, and likely anybody doing database interaction would just do it as a matter of course. So I'd ameliorate my comment substantially to include caveats about HOW you're interacting with Jet/ACE data.

Comment: Also note that since Access does NOT support multi-statement queries, it is probably much harder to inject.

Comment: @iDevlop: you're using a too-narrow definition of SQL Injection. Jet/ACE is still prone to leaking too much information, as you can pass it a `True=True` type of WHERE clause and get all the records. In a DML statement, that could also corrupt your data. But from my point of view, the scenario in which you're most exposed to that kind of hacking (on a website), Jet/ACE is not an appropriate data store in the first place...

Comment: I would add that when constructing queries like this, ALWAYS escape the variables. I have a little function called q() that single quotes and escapes the string, so: << where Name=" & q(myName) & " >>. Note that the above SQL will fail if the name is "O'Halloran".  And with escaping you get SQL injection protection for free as well.