# How to Insert Rows to MS Access 2003 Table in VB.net using Oledb Adapter / Command?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb, dataadapter

I have created a Form for Managing Contacts such as PhoneBook so i have created nearly 12 fields in MS Access 2003 including ID as a Primary Key(Auto Number)  the prob is while inserting the Data's (got from the user) into the Table.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class FrmMain

    Private Sub FrmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        connection_open()
    End Sub
    Dim adp As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable



    Private Sub BtnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
        Dim sql As String

        sql = "insert into TblContacts (FName, Company, Contact_1, Contact_2, Address, Email_1, Email_2, Web, SNS, Date_Saved, Cont_Image) values ('" & TxtFName.Text & "' ,'" & TxtCompany.Text & "','" & TxtCont_1.Text & "','" & TxtCont_2.Text & "','" & TxtAddress.Text & "','" & TxtEmail_1.Text & "','" & TxtEmail_2.Text & "','" & TxtWeb.Text & "','" & TxtSNS.Text & "',#" & TxtDate.Text & "#,'" & TextBox10.Text & "')"

        Try
            adp = New OleDbDataAdapter
            adp.InsertCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            adp.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()


            MsgBox("Saved Successfully!")

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.ToString)

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolStripButton3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton3.Click
        Try
            dt = New DataTable
            adp = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from TblContacts", con)
            adp.Fill(dt)

            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt


        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub


    'Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    '    ToolStripTextBox2.Text = Now
    'End Sub

End Class

**Connection Module:**

Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module connection_module

    Public con As New OleDbConnection
    Public Sub connection_open()
        Try
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                con.Close()
            End If
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Contacts.mdb"
            con.Open()

        Catch ex As Exception

            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

https://picasaweb.google.com/105381696083885067883/VBNet?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCPvqiqCrjqCAfQ&feat=directlink

Comment: The Screen Shot got lost somewhere?  So we cannot see what your error message is?

Comment: Stab in the dark, make sure your column names are correct.  Maybe SNS is SSN (social security number)?  Also, learn to use parameters.  Your query is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: @LarsTech:  Ooh, nice catch!  I'm betting on this one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name and image are [reserved words](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) in MS Access and need to be enclosed in brackets `[name]`

Is Date_Saved really text? If not the delimiters are #, not '

And, or course, @Lars point.

Finally, you [might like to consider parameters](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/357613/vb.net-code-to-insert-data-into-ms-access-database-with-parameters) or [Passing parameter to query for Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472563/passing-parameter-to-query-for-access-database)

Comment: i have re edited the question according to your advice and also added the link for the Images .. hope this will helpful to explain my question

Comment: I have tested an outline of your code, and `FName = "abc" : ADate = Now : sql = "insert into Table1 (AText, ADate) values ('" & FName & "',#" & ADate & "#)" : MsgBox(sql)` works for me, so I think you should check what you are getting from the textbox. However, there is really no need for you to use a textbox for the save date, because it is today, so `"insert into Table1 (AText, ADate) values ('" & FName & "',Now())"` should suit.

Comment: I should stress again that you will avoid an amazing number of problems with parameters. As it stands, if any of your textboxes contain a single quote ('), the query will fail.