# Update image in access database VB Net

Tags: vb.net

I got an error trying to update an image.

This is the code I used to do that:

Dim data() As Byte
        Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream
        Dim i As Short

```
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection

    conn = New OleDbConnection(kon)

    conn.Open()

    Dim sql As String = "UPDATE prop SET nmpr ='" & TextBox1.Text & "', peta = @peta where nmr ='" & ComboBox1.Text & "';"

    Try
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        'cmd.Connection = conn
        'cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        If PictureBox1 IsNot Nothing Then
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, PictureBox1.Image.RawFormat)
            data = ms.GetBuffer
        Else
            PictureBox1.Image = Nothing
        End If

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@peta", OleDbType.Binary).Value = data
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim Msg As String = "Unable to update"

        If ex IsNot Nothing Then
            Msg &= ":" & ControlChars.NewLine & ControlChars.NewLine & ex.ToString
        End If

        MessageBox.Show(Msg, My.Application.Info.AssemblyName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)

    End Try

    If (i > 0) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Sukses")
    End If

    conn.Close()
```

The error says:

> datatype mismatch in criteria expresion

i dont know which is mismatch, i just want to update image (peta) and nmpr field (texttbox.text)

Comment: Try to use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@peta", OleDbType.Binary).Value = data`

Comment: i try it but still error

Comment: You need to use the ? for parameters in your query. Check out this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/7486311/128221

Comment: What is the datatype of the field _nmpr_ in your database table?