# fill data to combo box depending upon another combo box value

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, combobox

i am connecting an Access database to my program using VB and i have two combo, i want the second combo data source is depending on the first combo selected item, here's the code that i made so far:

```
 Try
     Dim dbcon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\inventorysys.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        dbcon.Open()
        Dim sqlquery As String = ("SELECT DISTINCT Brand FROM inventory WHERE Category = ' " & catogerycombotxt.SelectedItem & " ' ")
        Dim comm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery, dbcon)
        Dim rs As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        dt.Load(rs)
        ' as an example set the ValueMember and DisplayMember'
        ' to two columns of the returned table'
        brandcombotxt.DataSource = dt
        brandcombotxt.ValueMember = "Brand"
        brandcombotxt.DisplayMember = "Brand"

        dbcon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

it works without errors but get no results, hope you can help me in that

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, I believe your problem is that in your query you are concatenating the selected value between two spaces:

```
Dim sqlquery As String = ("SELECT DISTINCT Brand FROM inventory WHERE Category = ' " & catogerycombotxt.SelectedItem & " ' ")
```

Should be

```
Dim sqlquery As String = ("SELECT DISTINCT Brand FROM inventory WHERE Category = '" & catogerycombotxt.SelectedItem & "'")
```

Second: learn about [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472563/passing-parameter-to-query-for-access-database). That's a better way to create and execute sql queries than string concatenation for many, many reasons.

Comment: i fix the the query but the code still not working, can you just show me how to t parameterized my query