# No value given for required parameters, with value

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I'm working in a c#/ASP.NET on a web app. 
As part of the app, I want to connect to an ms-access database, and get values from it into a `dataset`.

For some reason, I get the error in the title when filling the `dataset` with a `DataAdaptor`- despite this, when I use breakpoints, I can see the command is as follows:
`SELECT ..... WHERE ItemID = @value0` (if you need the parameters, ask for them and i`ll copy the whole thing).

I can also see that @value0 has the value 2 with breakpoints, and I am assured it's the only value in the query.

My question is, how could this happen? If the only value in the query is filled, what am I missing?

**EDIT**:
Full query:
`SELECT ItemName as Name,ItemPicture as Picture,ItemHeroModif as Assistance,ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems FROM Item WHERE ItemID = @value0"`

Full building code (Generating the query for each user requires a different amount of items, this one has only a single item, so i've used it to test):

```
static public DataSet getUserShopItemDS(string username,List<shopItem> items)
{
string madeForCommand = "SELECT ItemName as Name,ItemPicture as Picture,ItemHeroModif as Assistance,ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems FROM Item WHERE ItemID = ";
        int count = 0;
        foreach (shopItem item in items)
        {
            madeForCommand += "@value"+count+" OR ";
            count++;
        }
        madeForCommand = madeForCommand.Substring(0, madeForCommand.Length - 3);
        OleDbCommand command = GenerateConnection(madeForCommand);
        for (int ii = 0; ii < items.Count; ii++)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value" + ii, items[ii].ID);
        }
        var FreestyleAdaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        FreestyleAdaptor.SelectCommand = command;
        DataSet Items = new DataSet();
        FreestyleAdaptor.Fill(Items);//The error is thrown here.
        return Items;
    }
```

**EDIT 2:** - The shopitem class:

```
public class shopItem
{
    //Irrelevant parameters,
    public int ID // Whenever a user logs in, I create a list of his items, and attach each one it's ID from the database. I send the list as a parameter to the function.
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public shopItem(int ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
    public shopItem() { }
    // more constructors.
}
```

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Seems to be a very easy problem to solve, but we definitely need to see the code :-)

Comment: @PaoloCosta That's great to hear - editted (:

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code you should use:

```
        var madeForCommand = "SELECT ItemName as Name,ItemPicture as Picture,ItemHeroModif as Assistance,ItemTroopModif as Charisma, HerbCost as Herbs, GemCost as Gems FROM Item WHERE ";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();

        for (int ii = 0; ii < items.Count; ii++)
        {
            madeForCommand += "ItemId = ?  OR ";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("value" + ii, items[ii].ID);
        }

        madeForCommand = madeForCommand.Substring(0, madeForCommand.Length - 3);
```

In MS Access parameters are passed using ? and have to be provided in the same order as they are used in the query.

Comment: Thank you very much, That will solve future problems - however, in my case, I only had one item for the user, so it did not solve my current problem. +1 (:

Comment: Try to debug this line of code and see what you set as a parameter value command.Parameters.AddWithValue(substr, items[numOutOfSubstr].ID);

Comment: Anyway, your code seems to be really buggy, the ItemId has to be repeated foreach OR condition, so remove it from the first string and add it in the loop: madeForCommand += " ItemId = @value"+count+" OR ";

Comment: The ID is 2 - which is the way it should be; That's exacly the reason I`m confused. I didn't understand your second comment though, sorry :/ can you rephrase it / edit your post?

Comment: If you add the definition of the class shopItem I can provide a solution. The way you parse the query in order to find the parameters is really strange

Comment: Editted with the relevant class details.

Comment: This is a much better way to do this, Thank you very very much. I really want to give you the checkmark, the problem is, i still get `No value given for one or more required parameters.` :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76272/discussion-between-paolo-costa-and-a-abramov).

Comment: Ithink zou pass parameters with the wrong syntax, use ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472563/passing-parameter-to-query-for-access-database

Comment: That is VB, I am using C#.

Comment: I updated the answer for MS Access but I cannot test it. Can you check if it works now?

Comment: So, I don't know how to help you more, you should debug the class FreestyleAdaptor, I don't know how it behaves, and see what you parameters you pass to the command.