# Syntax error missing operator in query

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am trying to select multiple columns from my access D.B. I am receiving this error: `syntax error missing operator in query expression`.

```
 Dim command As New OleDbCommand("Select [SC1],[SC2],[SC3],[PC1],[PC2],[PC3],Model,[AirFlow],[SSC1],[SSC2],[SSC3],[CRC1],[CRC2],[CRC3],[TSWT1],[TSWT2] from NewChilled where [rows1]=" & CDbl(ComboBox10.Text) & "and Speed='" & ComboBox13.Text & "'and [Id_Model=]" & i & "", conn)
 Dim DT As New DataTable
 Dim DA As New OleDbDataAdapter(command)
 DA.Fill(DT)
```

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?  It seems to be a clear question that includes the code that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have `[Id_Model=]"` should be `[Id_Model]="`

You really should [parameterize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472563/passing-parameter-to-query-for-access-database) your query to make it easier to spot issues like this and to prevent sql injection in your code.