# SQL Server wildcard LIKE search

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, wildcard

I am trying to filter records by using a wildcard

```
sSubStr = "WHERE [Document Name] LIKE '%" + sFilter + "%' "
```

All works fine when I try to find part of the column `[Document Name]` that consists of alphabetic characters but doesn't return anything when I use a combination with numbers, like `DIB20200118`.

Example data: THIS.IS.MY.DOCUMENT.NAME.DIB20200118.20210332.DOC

Comment: Elaborate `fails`. Give sample data, a sample input and your expected result.

Comment: I tried your sample data and found it did match. It could be that there are invisible characters in the data or the search term. What is the data type of the `[Document Name]` column?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's a TEXT field in a MS ACCESS database

Comment: Ah, I tried it in SQL Server, as that is what the tags said; I have edited them for you so that someone familiar with Access is more likely to see the question.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I wrote SQL Server because I am programming in VB.NET and use the % wildcard, while in Access the * wildcard is used

Comment: You have to use the wildcard character for the database you're using, which in this case would be `*`. Also, you really should use an SQL parameter for the value, otherwise it will go horribly wrong when there is an apostrophe in the search term (or someone tries an SQL injection attack and steals or deletes all the data).

Comment: I´m not an ms access pro but I guess there is some encoding/datatype mismatch. Btw..have you debugged and inspect sFilter  right before the query is executed? Does it exactly contains what you expect?

Comment: @AndrewMorton can you give an example of a SQL parameter?

Comment: @Marco Please see [Passing parameter to query for Access database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486311/1115360), or if that does not have enough information then a (google) search for "vb.net access sql parameterized query example" will give more possibilities.

Comment: @AlexB. I tried your suggestion and get the following string: "SELECT Id,[Document Type],[Document Name],DIBnummer,XPostnummer,[Last Accessed],[Document Location] FROM Archief WHERE [Document Name] LIKE '%dib2021003289%' ORDER BY Id DESC"

Comment: `dib2021003289` is not `DIB20200118` or did you use another example here?

Comment: @AlexB. I used another example

Comment: Should try the * wildcard.

Comment: Can results depend on the database connection? Return New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\FileRename v5.4.accdb")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that changing the way the Listview is filled made the difference. Somehow the first record was never shown after loading the Listview. The record count was always one short.

```
Dim sSQL As String
            Dim sSubStr As String
            If sFilter = "" Then
                sSQL = "SELECT Id,[Document Type],[Document Name],DISnummer,XPostnummer,[Last Accessed],[Document Location] FROM Archief ORDER BY Id DESC"
            Else
                sSubStr = "WHERE [Document Name] LIKE '%" + sFilter + "%' "
                sSQL = "SELECT Id,[Document Type],[Document Name],DISnummer,XPostnummer,[Last Accessed],[Document Location] FROM Archief " + sSubStr + " ORDER BY Id DESC"
            End If
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sSQL, con)
            Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Dim dis As String
                Dim docImage As VariantType
                Dim items As New List(Of ListViewItem)

                If dr.HasRows() Then

                    ListView1.BeginUpdate()
                    ListView1.Items.Clear()

                    While dr.Read
                        If dr("Document Type").ToString = "PDF" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "pdf" Then
                            docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 1)
                        ElseIf dr("Document Type").ToString = "doc" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "docx" Then
                            docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 3)
                        ElseIf dr("Document Type").ToString = "ppt" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "pptx" Then
                            docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 2)
                        ElseIf dr("Document Type").ToString = "xls" Or dr("Document Type").ToString = "xlsx" Then
                            docImage = (ImageList1.Images.Count - 4)
                        End If

                        dis = dr("Last Accessed").Substring(0, dr("Last Accessed").IndexOf(" "))
                        items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {"", dr("Document Name").ToString, dr("DISnummer").ToString, dr("XPostnummer").ToString, dis, dr("Id").ToString, dr("Document Location").ToString}, docImage))

                    End While
                    ListView1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray)
                    ListView1.EndUpdate()
                Else
                    MsgBox("Nothing was found.",, Title)
                End If
                dr.Close()

            End Using
```